# Can we make the Pseudo Element tag a synonym of CSS Content?

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I've only just discovered the [pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) tag. Pseudo elements in CSS are defined by the [CSS Generated Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/) specification, which uses the URL path `/css-content-*` (where `*` is the version).

We already have a [css-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-content) tag, but unfortunately this has significantly fewer questions than [pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) does, meaning I am unable to request a tag synonym.

Despite having fewer questions, "css-content" better reflects what these are and conforms to how other tags on CSS are written ([css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors), [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms), [css-animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animation), etc.)

Could [pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) please be made into a synonym of [css-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-content)?

Comment: Looks like we also have a [pseudo-class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-class) tag which could probably be merged with [css-selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors).

Comment: Related, but deleted, question on SO: [Why ::first-letter / ::first-line / ::selection are called pseudo-elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property) (it's heavily downvoted, but it's actually a good question, and the premise of this very meta question shows)

Comment: @Stephen Why did you retag this question from [support] to [discussion]? Aside from the utter triviality of such an edit, it is well established that synonym requests are actually support requests, since that is effectively a moderator-only feature. (Technically, anyone with a score of 5 or more in the tag can propose a synonym, but we all know that doesn’t really work in practice. And even if it did, support would still be an appropriate tag, since this is literally a request for assistance with one of the site’s features.)

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry about that, I thought it was mistagged but evidently I was mistaken. Why: I'm helping out in the Trogdor chat room on pass 2 of outstanding burnination and synonym requests. I have been suitably advised.

Answer (score 6):

> Pseudo elements in CSS are defined by the CSS Generated Content specification

Incorrect. Pseudo-elements are defined in [section 2 of CSS1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#pseudo-classes-and-pseudo-elements), [section 5.12 of CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/selector.html#pseudo-element-selectors), [section 7 of css3-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements), and split into two level 4 modules: the syntax in [section 3.6 of selectors-4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#pseudo-elements) and the pseudo-elements themselves in [css-pseudo-4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4).

The generated content section of CSS2 and css-content-3 define the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, but only those. They don't define pseudo-elements as a whole.

Questions about the `content` property should be tagged [css-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-content), and questions about `::before`, `::after`, or any other pseudo-element for that matter should be tagged [pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element). The two tags don't have to be mutually exclusive — if a question is about the use of `content` in `::before` or `::after` specifically then there is nothing wrong with adding both tags. But they mean different things, and are therefore not synonyms.

Comment: That's fair enough. If not css-content, why do we need separate tags for pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements when they can be categorised under css-selectors?

Comment: @James Donnelly: You know, I find [pseudo-class] kind of unnecessary too. But pseudo-elements are more than just the selectors. Many pseudo-element questions aren't really about selector syntax but the functionality of the pseudo-elements themselves. Like the one about the content property - which is about the property, not the selector syntax.

Comment: @James Donnelly: Then again, every pseudo-element is different - categorising all pseudo-element questions under [pseudo-element] seems odd, now that I think about it.