# Remove the [pseudo-element] -> [css] synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-removal-request

Today I noticed that [pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) is a synonym of [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) which is a surprise to me.

Pseudo elements are part of the [CSS Selectors Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#pseudo-elements) and they are complex enough to deserve a tag. We cannot even consider them as synonym of [css-selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-selectors) because the have their own *issues* and tricks.

One example of question around pseudo element: [Font Awesome 5 on pseudo elements shows square instead of icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754892/8620333)

There is also an online documentation about [how to use Font Awesome 5 with pseudo element](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) which make the topic not trivial.

Our [CSS master BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)<sup>1</sup> wrote a [lot around Pseudo elements](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A106224%20%22pseudo%20elements%22) (125 posts tagged with [pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-elements)).

He also said:

> @James Donnelly: You know, I find [pseudo-class] kind of unnecessary too. But pseudo-elements are more than just the selectors. Many pseudo-element questions aren't really about selector syntax but the functionality of the pseudo-elements themselves. Like the one about the content property - which is about the property, not the selector syntax. – BoltClock♦ Mar 24 '17 at 11:34  <sup>[ref](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345927/8620333)</sup>

---

The JS people will also agree that dealing with pseudo element is a tricky exercice and a lot of question are asked around this topic. The following question: [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5041494/8620333) is one of the frequent question in the JS and CSS tag (can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?tab=frequent&page=5&pagesize=15= and also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css?tab=frequent )

We also find questions tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) without having [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css):

[How to delete Pseudo-elements with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29118543/8620333)

[Is it possible to select pseudo elements like scrollbars using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56961302/8620333)

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22pseudo+elements%22+-%5Bcss%5D

<sub>1: If I am able to summon him he will for sure agree with me.</sub>

Comment: FWIW I agree this probably should not be a synonym of CSS. At least not unless we are ready to make all CSS-related tags synonyms of CSS as well...

Comment: I sacrificed a 13mm nut and a Seiko to summon BoltClock. Give it 6-8...

Comment: @Machavity what about the incantation? did you do it correctly? if not you may lose your Diamond ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Pseudo elements are part of the CSS Selectors Specification and they are complex enough to deserve a tag.

They're also complex enough to have [their own specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4).

Anyway, thanks to Bhargav,

```css
.status {
  display: inline-block;
}

.status.neg::first-line {
  background-color: #fcc;
}

.status.neg::after {
  content: ' no longer';
}
```

```html
<p>[pseudo-element] <span class="status neg">is</span> a synonym of [css].
```

Comment: Obviously this is really bad advice in terms of semantics and should never be emulated in production (which I'm going to peg the downvote to whether or not it was the intended reason).

Comment: ah, the summon of machavity was a success ;) .. I am gonna buy some Seiko just in case.

Answer (score 5):

Given the overwhelming support to remove the synonym, I went ahead and deleted the synonym. It was created in July this year by the community, and a total of 19 renames were done over the past month.

[pseudo-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-element) is now its own tag, and has 1829 questions. If there's a reason to re-synonymize this, then feel free to open a new post asking for a synonym.

Comment: *a  total of 19 renames were done over the past month.* --> can this be fixed by adding the tag again?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately we don't have a list of those posts.

Comment: even a *complex* SEDE query cannot do it? something like: searching the posts without the tag X but having the tag X in a previous revision?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I don't think so. The tag isn't saved when the question is created, they get remapped as soon as the user types it in. I assume that there must be some dev tool that can find out those posts that were remapped, but I am not aware of one.

Comment: Wait, I think we didn't understand each other. I was not talking about the tag remap when a user create a new question. I was talking about old questiosn already having the tag and after the synonimization and edit was done and the tag was removed. The tag was already present in an old version of the post. I am trying to identiy such posts.

Comment: @TheMaster the link is broken for me ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1264905/1557920/who-added-this-tag-to-the-question)  might help.

Comment: @TemaniAfif just look at [the number of renames on synonyms list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)

Comment: @Braiam yes but I want the list of the posts to re-edit them :(